# How to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ne^{-\sqrt{nx}} \sin{x}}{(1+x^{2})\arctan{x}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory

I know that I must use theorem of dominanted convergence,to bound function under integral.  I tried to solve that in two ways. First of all, I tried the method of substitute, to use that $t=\arctan{x}$, and than i got  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{ne^{-\sqrt{n\tan{t}}}}{t} dx$,( $\sin{(\tan{t})}$ is always < 1 ).But i don't think that anything good  can be done with that. Secondly, I tried to substitute nx=t, but in that case, i really don't know what to do with $\arctan{t/n}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,1].$ Claim:

$$\int_0^1 ne^{-\sqrt {nx}}f(x)\,dx \to 2f(0).$$

Proof: Let $x=y^2/n.$ The integral becomes

$$\int_0^{\sqrt n} e^{-y} 2yf(y^2/n)\, dy= \int_0^\infty \chi_{[0,\sqrt n]}(y) e^{-y} 2yf(y^2/n)\, dy. $$

The integrands on the right converge pointwise on $[0,\infty)$ to $e^{-y} 2yf(0),$ and  are bounded in absolute value by $\|f\|_\infty e^{-y} 2y\in L^1[0,\infty).$ By the DCT, the integrals converge to

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-y} 2yf(0)\, dy = 2f(0).$$

In our problem, $f(x)= (\sin x)/[(1+x^2)\arctan x],$ which we can regard as continuous on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=1.$ Thus the limit we seek is $2.$

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

You already received good answers; I looked at this interesting problem from another point of view.
 Writing
$$\frac{\sin (x)}{\left(1+x^2\right) \tan ^{-1}(x)}=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^{2k}$$ we then face the problem of
$$I_k=n\int_0^1 x^{2 k} e^{-\sqrt{n x}}\,dx=2 n^{-2 k} \left(\Gamma (4 k+2)-\Gamma \left(4 k+2,\sqrt{n}\right)\right)$$

Summing and expanding the result as a series for large values of $n$, we can find the asymptotics
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{n e^{-\sqrt{n x}} \sin (x)}{\left(1+x^2\right) \tan ^{-1}(x)}\, dx=2-\frac{200}{n^2}+\cdots$$ which seems to be a reasonable approximation when compared to the results of numerical integration
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 100 & 1.980000000 & 1.982384694 \\
 200 & 1.995000000 & 1.995238623 \\
 300 & 1.997777778 & 1.997832134 \\
 400 & 1.998750000 & 1.998768199 \\
 500 & 1.999200000 & 1.999207664 \\
 600 & 1.999444444 & 1.999448199 \\
 700 & 1.999591837 & 1.999593884 \\
 800 & 1.999687500 & 1.999688708 \\
 900 & 1.999753086 & 1.999753844 \\
 1000 & 1.999800000 & 1.999800499
\end{array}
\right)$$